# Problem with Outlook displaying an html message

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am sending an html formatted email message using MailMessage class. Code is as follows:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.body = "<html><body><b>test message</b></body></html>";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
....... skipped To/From settings - irrelevant .......
new SmtpClient().Send(message);
```

When I see this received message in Outlook, it shows the whole html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>
            test message
        </b>
    </body>
</html>
```

instead of just bolded **text message**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering what is in the "skipped" part . . . I'm thinking there is something in the "irrelevant" part we need to know.

Comment: This exact code works for me in Office 2007 - which version of office are you running? Do you have any policies or settings that might be affecting the rendering? (When I say exact, I mean the part where you set the Body and the IsBodyHtml properties) screen shot: http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/2193/soq4719686.jpg

Comment: @Frank - the skipped part is where I assign message.To and message.From

Comment: @Tr1stan: if you right click and chose to see source, what do you see? For me it shows encoded text like &lt;b&gt;

Comment: @Andrey: Source is as you'd expect. `<html><body><b>test message</b></body></html>`

Comment: @Tr1stan - I found a fix - take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it by putting html version of the email into message.AlternateViews instead of message.Text

Answer (score 0):

1) If you're running Outlook 2003 on windows 7, there was a known issue when trying to render emails with "Undisclosed-recipients" set. A patch was released, can't seem to find it atm. Does this sound like it could be your problem?

2) Check your virus scanner is not causing the problem

3) Do HTML emails render correctly from other sources? If they aren't then perhaps something between the sender and the recipient (even if they are both you) might be causing the issue.

Comment: I'm running Outlook 2010 on Windows 7, but it also happens with Outlook 2007 on Vista and XP

Comment: @Andrey Do you have a virus scanner running that is integrated with your client? if so try disabling it...

Comment: @Andrey: Also, do any HTML emails that you read in your client render correctly?

Comment: I do have a virus scanner on my host box, but my dev VM's don't and I see the same behavior there. And it does show other html emails correctly - I get a bunch of advertisement spam which I wish was showing garbage :)